# spring security login pages?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I have some confusion with how spring security works:

In my application, I need to have a login page for users after which they are redirected back the page from where they came.  I went through a few spring security tutorials and read some articles, and the examples work by securing a certain page on a site (managed by the `<intercept url ..>` tag).  Then Spring security will generate a login page (or you can specify your own) in order to access the secured page.

I am confused because I don't want to necessary secure a given page on my site: I want a login page for users to log into after which they have access to elevated features of the site (through spring security's authorization features).  My question is: given what I described, what would be the strategy to create this login page which, after login, would grant the logged in user the appropriate authorities?

The hack I thought of would be to create a simple JSP page who's only function is to redirect back to the previous page.  Then I would use Spring Security to secure that JSP page.  But it seems like there should be a better way of doing this...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user is not logged in yet, you could treat him as ANONYMOUS. So the page will hide everything marked with `<sec:authorize ifAllGranted="ROLE_SUPERVISOR">`.
See [Anonymous Authentication](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.x/reference/anonymous.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if you still need an answer since your question was in feb., but once the user has logged in via SS, you can get the SS Authentication object in your controller as:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

What I do is I create my own Authentication class and wrap it around Spring's Authentication class so if I ever change providers I just extend my Authentication class with a new provider.  Then I put my wrapper in the session so I can query the authentication object via OGNL anytime I want to know if someone is logged in and what the details are.

ie:

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
if (auth.isAuthenticated()) {
    session.put("authentication", auth);
}
```

to logoff, simply invalidate the session

```
session.invalidate();
```

I also do kind of a trick with SS.  Since SS automatically provides the form login when accessing a secured realm (same workflow as j_security_check), you can define the login to point to a page that doesn't exist in the secured realm:

```
<a href="my_secured_realm/non_existant_page">click here to sign in</a>
```

SS will then fire up the login page.  Then whatever framework you are using, you can intercept after the login to get the Authentication object.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `always-use-default-target="false"` so that spring security will redirect automatically to the previous page, if it is set to true, it will always take to default home page. The property is on `form-login` tag.

Comment: Thanks.  But do you think you could give more details to help me out with my specific question?  Basically I'd like to know how to use spring security to create a login page to provide elevate access.  Everything I've found so far explains how to secure a certain page. I want to be able to display different things to the user based on his/her ROLE (using JSP tags)...thanks

Comment: Spring security has security tags, using which you can control the content in the jsp, for example using `<sec:authorize ifAllGranted="ROLE_SUPERVISOR">`, you can show certain content only to users with role as supervisor. Is this the functionality you are looking for?

Comment: Yes.  But I am still confused.  Basically I need a login page who's purpose is to elevate the users' role (once they login successfully).  Maybe you could point me to references on how to do this, because all tutorials I found are on how to restrict access to an entire page...